# Visual Studio 2017 crashes when attempting to open an SSAS Tabular Model.bim file

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ssas, tabular, ssas-tabular

I am on a Windows 7 64 bit machine running Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise 15.9.22, SQL Server Data Tools 15.1.62002.01090, SQL Server Management Studio 15.0.18330.0.  I have been working on SQL Server Analysis Services 2019 tabular model for several weeks now and last Friday I was no longer able to open the Model.bim file.  I can still open and run an SSIS package that reads from the SSAS Server.  This only happens when I try to open the Model.bim.

The first error messages that I began receiving were that it could no longer find the localhost workspace server.

[Tabular Model Designer - You cannot open the BIM file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ww2p.png)

After getting this error message I switched the Integrated Workspace Mode to False and then added our DEV SSAS 2019 server in the Workspace Server field.

I did not add/remove any programs prior to this happening, however my IT team installed CrowdStrike on my client the night before it stopped working.  They went in and uninstalled it but the error messages are still there.  Since then CrowdStrike has been re-installed.

Resolution Steps attempted:
I applied the updates to Visual Studio 2017 and SQL Server Management Studio.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio.  I have tried removing components to simplify the installation, but I always end up with the same errors.

Latest Windows Update:
Was about 15 days ago, but I was able to open this same Model.bim file 4 days ago.

First error message after changing to Development environment as workspace server...
[Tabular Model Designer - An error occurred while opening the model on the workspace database.  Reason: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.BackEnd.DAXServices' threw an exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtrQv.png)

> ## ============================ Error Message:
>
> An error occurred while opening the model on the workspace database.
>   Reason: The type initializer for
>   'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.BackEnd.DAXServices' threw an exception.
>
> ## ============================ Call Stack:
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.VSHost.VSHostManager.PrepareSandbox(Boolean
>   newProject, Boolean& isRefreshNeeded, Boolean& isImpersonationChanged,
>   Boolean& saveRequired, List`1& truncatedTables, Boolean
>   isRealTimeMode, Int32 clientCompatibilityLevel)    at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.VSHost.Integration.EditorFactory.CreateEditorInstance(UInt32
>   grfCreateDoc, String pszMkDocument, String pszPhysicalView,
>   IVsHierarchy pvHier, UInt32 itemid, IntPtr punkDocDataExisting,
>   IntPtr& ppunkDocView, IntPtr& ppunkDocData, String&
>   pbstrEditorCaption, Guid& pguidCmdUI, Int32& pgrfCDW)
>
> ============================

After getting the first error message, any time trying to open the Model.bim after that gives the following error message...
[devenv.exe - Application Error: The instruction at 0x7733e8fb referenced memory at 0x41980024.  The memory could not be read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc75J.png)

I tried to hit Cancel to go into the debugger, but it crashes VS2017 too fast and I get the following message...
[Unable to attach to the crashing process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYBLu.png)

Comment: Since posting this I have upgraded to Visual Studio 2019, but I am still getting the same error messages.  This is from the Event Viewer:

The description for Event ID 0 from source MSOLAP$DataToolsInstance:24f05905-b0b0-4865-8fa5-ca8c67d28958 cannot be found. 

The following error occurred while loading an external library 'msmgdsrv.dll': %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer because I don't know what caused or resolved the original problem.  I tried doing the install on two additional Windows 7 clients and then a Windows 10 client.  Both Win7 clients had the same issue, but Win10 did not have the issue so I was allowed to keep the Win10 client.

Comment: My colleage just engaged the same issue on his Windows 7 laptop, exactly the same issue leads me to this post. He was able to work on tabular project on his VS 2017. I have him install 2019 (brand new + MS Analysis VSIX extension) and still faces the same issue. 

On the SSAS (server/instance), the model is created and left behind. 
I am thinking if there is anything wrong (windows) in the past two weeks kill the feature.

Comment: Sorry to hear that @Chjquest, I wish I could tell you what caused this or how to resolve it.  I also posted this to the Visual Studio Developer Community https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1021940/visual-studio-analysis-services-tabular-cant-open.html and they are going to take a look at it at some point.

Comment: Tum, is there a way you can "Restore" (System Recovery) those systems to earlier time frame ? My colleague has no past restore point except today (No idea why). I believe this is caused by Windows Updates, but can't be sure.

Comment: @Chjquest it sounds like your user does not have System Restore configured.  If your clients are backed up somewhere you could restore from there.  I know in our organization our systems are not backed up, but our system drives are.  You can check this by clicking on the Windows key and typing Restore, the first item on the list should be Create System Restore Point or something similar to that.  Anything along those lines should get you to the correct screen in the System Properties.  If Configure or System Restore are grayed out then the user does not have permissions to access this section.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, our laptops/devices are managed by the IT team and we (user) have very limited permission to change/manage/control the system. During this pandemic, we are all WFH so it's kind of hard to get replacement. I managed to work on another way to resolve this need for my colleague temporarily through another computer. 

I also go to the link you post before, looks like there is another one "victim" now saying the same issue.

Comment: I've just run into this same issue, opening my tabular model just kicks me out of Visual Studio. I tried open with and used default and it threw me an error (index out of range) but that was never resolved in the microsoft forums... Did you guys manage to resolve??

Answer (score 0):

OK, so to resolve...

Delete the folder from source control on local machine
Open visual studio without code.
Open Source control explorer
Right click the full folder - Advanced - Tick both overwrite boxes and then GET.
Then open the solution
Right click the model and open with designer.